# example for a strictly increasing function which has a discontinuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I want an example for a function $f$ which is strictly increasing in some subset $S$ of $ℝ$ such that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous on $f(S)$.I came up with my own example but I need to verify it.

$$f(x)=x ; x∊[0,1]$$

$$f(x)=2x; x∊(1,2]$$

I would appreciate if some one could tell if my example is incorrect and if so provide a better example.Thank you

Comment: But $f^{-1}(x)=x $. Besides, the inverse of a linear map is linear, and linear maps in $\mathbb R$ are always continuous.

Comment: Your example does have a continuous inverse: $f^{-1}(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ and $f^{-1}(x)=x/2$ on $(2,4]$. Is $S$ to be just any subset of ${\bf R}$?

Comment: the function you made up is itself discontinous at x=1 , yes?

Comment: @DBFdalwayse what about my example in my comment?

Comment: I edited my comment sorry hope it fixes it

Comment: @Rajinda: Then you need to worry about the existence of the inverse. Notice $f^{-1}$ is not defined in $(9,1]$. For a right inverse to exist, you need $f$ to be 1-1, for a left inverse, you need $f$ to be onto. If you want a 2-sided inverse (in which case right- inverse =left- inverse, then you want f to be 1-1 and onto).

Comment: @DBFdalwayse  if i take f(x)=x when x∊[0,1) and f(x)=1 what x=2 ?

Comment: Your example function works; the inverse is not continuous at $x=2$. I meant the function in your post. And I should more carefully state: a function f(x)=ax+b from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is continuous , even uniformly-continuous, but if you define it piecewise, it may be discontinuous.

Comment: How about the function $e^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not have a positive answer, the only way to get discontinuity of the inverse or pseudo inverse is for f to be flat in some intervals. As pointed in the comments, if f itself has discontinuities in S then f(S) is going to be a collection of disjoint intervals such that the inverse in continuous in each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Every strict monotone function $f\colon J\to\boldsymbol R$, defined on an interval $J$, has an inverse $f^{-1}\colon f(J)\to\boldsymbol R$.  It is little known that this inverse is *continuos* even if $f$ itself is not continuos.

Answer (score 0):

f(x)=x ;0<=x<=1

f(x)=x/2 ;x in (2,4]

clearly f is strictly increasing on given interval.

but inverse of f is    let it is g.  then g(x)=x; 0<=x<=1  and g(x)=2x ; x in (1,2].

clearly g is not continuous on x=1.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)